# Phone gap code is not working

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, cordova

> Contact Example
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.7.0.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
>
> // Wait for Cordova to load
> //
> document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
>
> // Cordova is ready
> //
> function onDeviceReady() {
>     var myContact = navigator.contacts.create({"displayName": "Test User"});
>     myContact.note = "This contact has a note.";
>     console.log("The contact, " + myContact.displayName + ", note: " + myContact.note);
> }
>
>
> </script>   </head>   <body>
> <h1>Example</h1>
> <p>Create Contact</p>   </body> </html>
> ```

I Compiled this code and tried on my android contacts not creating Test user"

Comment: so can u please give me a working code to save a contact

Comment: See below.  It's all in the phonegap documentation... http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_contacts_contacts.md.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `save()` after you create the contact and populate the properties...

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    var myContact = navigator.contacts.create({"displayName": "Test User"});
    myContact.note = "This contact has a note.";
    myContact.save(function() {
        console.log("contact saved");
    },
    function() {
        console.log("could not save contact");
    });
    console.log("The contact, " + myContact.displayName + ", note: " + myContact.note);
}
```

Comment: please give me complete html, i am new to this

Comment: I've changed it to be the complete `onDeviceReady` function :)